# swig/python: object does not support indexing

Tags: python, c++, swig

Given this set of files:

foo.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

template <class T0> class Foo {
  public:
    T0 m[3];

    Foo(const T0 &a, const T0 &b, const T0 &c) {
        m[0] = a;
        m[1] = b;
        m[2] = c;
    }
    void info() { printf("%d %d %d\n", m[0], m[1], m[2]); }
    // T0 &operator[](int id) { return ((T0 *)m)[id]; }
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

foo.i (Attempt1):

```
%module foo

%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%include "foo.h"

%template(intFoo) Foo<int>;

%extend Foo{
    T0& __getitem__(int id) { return ((T0 *)m)[id]; }
}
```

setup.py:

```
import os
import sys
from setuptools import setup, Extension

foo_module = Extension('_foo',
                           sources=[
                               'foo.i',
                               'foo.cpp'
                           ],
                           swig_opts=['-c++', '-py3', '-builtin'],
                           include_dirs=['.']
                           )

setup(name='foo',
      version='0.1',
      platforms=['Windows', 'Linux'],
      ext_modules=[foo_module],
      py_modules=["foo"],
      )
```

test.py:

```
from foo import intFoo

a = intFoo(10,20,30)
print(dir(a))
a.info()
print(a[2])
```

I build the extension running:

```
python setup.py build_ext --force -i
```

but when i try to run test.py i'll get:

```
TypeError: 'foo.intFoo' object does not support indexing
```

The statement `extend` in `foo.i` is the answer suggested on any other SO related threads, that means I'm using it incorrectly here. Could anyone explain how to fix this so when i run `test.py` is able to use the `[]` operator succesfully?

Another attempts:

- Attempt2:

  ```
  %module foo

  %{
  #include "foo.h"
  %}

  %include "foo.h"

  %template(intFoo) Foo<int>;

  %extend intFoo{
      T0& __getitem__(int id) { return ((T0 *)m)[id]; }
  }
  ```

  Throws this error `TypeError: 'foo.intFoo' object does not support indexing`
- Attempt3

  ```
  %module foo

  %{
  #include "foo.h"
  %}

  %include "foo.h"

  %extend Foo{
      T0& __getitem__(int id) { return ((T0 *)m)[id]; }
  }

  %template(intFoo) Foo<int>;
  ```

  Throws this error `foo_wrap.cpp(3808): error C2065: 'm': undeclared identifier`

Comment: Try `%extend intFoo` or move the `%extend Foo` before `%template(intFoo)`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Tried your suggestions and edited the question, unfortunately, no luck :(

Comment: As far as I know, the `%extend` feature does not work together with the `-builtin` option

Comment: It's nice to see a question with setup.py and all the files needed for efficient reproduction of your problem.

Comment: FWIW, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736700/how-to-extend-a-templated-c-class-in-python-with-swig-to-allow-the-operator. This question cannot closed as a duplicate due to the open bounty.

Comment: @RSahu it's not quite a duplicate because the addition of the `-builtin` flag makes it necessary to use the slots mechanism, besides the templates complexity.

Comment: @Flexo, I am not familiar with Swig with that level of depth. I trust your judgement.

Comment: @RSahu Few days ago I had already taken a look to the question you'd mentioned and others and tried, of course they didn't help at all, otherwise i hadn't opened this one.

Comment: @BPL, It might be worthwhile to mention that in your post, and maybe point out why those answers did not work for you. It will definitely improve your question, if nothing else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Throughout this example I'm working with your first version of foo.i)

First up the `%extend` you've got needs to be specified before the `%template` directive to have any effect.

Once we fix that we now get a compiler error from your `%extend` code:

```
foo_wrap.cpp: In function 'int& Foo_Sl_int_Sg____getitem__(Foo<int>*, int)':
foo_wrap.cpp:3705:85: error: 'm' was not declared in this scope
```

This happens because the methods you add with `%extend` aren't really members of the class you're adding them to. To access `m` in this context we need to refer to it with `$self->m` instead. SWIG will [replace `$self`](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_class_extension) with the appropriate variable for us. (It's worth a quick peek at the generated code to understand how this works)

One useful tip when debugging typemaps or extensions is to search for the code you wrote in the generated output from SWIG - if it's not there then it isn't being applied how you thought.

So once we fix the error about `m` not being declared we have another problem because you've compiled with `-builtin`:

```
In [1]: import foo

In [2]: f=foo.intFoo(1,2,3)

In [3]: f[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e71eec16918d> in <module>()
----> 1 f[0]

TypeError: 'intFoo' object does not support indexing

In [4]: f.__getitem__(0)
Out[4]: <Swig Object of type 'int *' at 0xa8807d40>
```

Even though you've added `__getitem__`, indexing with `f[n]` still doesn't work. That's happening because with pure C-API classes in Python operator overloading doesn't work the same way. You've added a `__getitem__` method successfully, but Python is looking in the [builtin type's slots](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_builtin_overloads) (specifically mp_subscript) for a way to perform the operation. So we need to fix that too. With that done a working foo.i looks like:

```
%module foo

%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%feature("python:slot", "mp_subscript", functype="binaryfunc") Foo::__getitem__;

%include "foo.h"

%extend Foo{
    T0& __getitem__(int id) { return ((T0 *)$self->m)[id]; }
}

%template(intFoo) Foo<int>;
```

So now we can do what you want:

```
In [1]: import foo

In [2]: f=foo.intFoo(1,2,3)

In [3]: f[0]
Out[3]: <Swig Object of type 'int *' at 0xb4024100>
```

(You don't actually have to call it `__getitem__` any more, because the function gets registered in the slots, it should be possible to call the `operator[]` without `%extend` at all for instance)

Finally you probably want to change the return type to `const T0&`, or write a Python type to proxy objects for non-const int reference better.

Comment: It works great, but without the `const` in front of  `T0&`, the return type becomes a `Swig Object of type 'int *'`. With the `const` added it becomes an integer.

Answer (score 3):

I have changed the wrong answer (stating that `%extent` could only be used without the `-builtin` option) to something that works, but again only without the 'built-in' option

setup.py

```
import os
import sys
from setuptools import setup, Extension

foo_module = Extension('_foo',
                           sources=[
                               'foo.i', 'foo.cpp'
                           ],
                           swig_opts=['-c++'],
                           include_dirs=['.']
                           )

setup(name='foo',
      version='0.1',
      platforms=['Windows', 'Linux'],
      ext_modules=[foo_module],
      py_modules=["foo"],
      )
```

foo.i

```
%module foo

%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%include "carrays.i"
%array_functions(int, intArray);

%include "foo.h"

%extend Foo<int> {
%pythoncode %{
def __getitem__(self, id):
  return _foo.intArray_getitem(self.m,id)             
%}
};

%template(intFoo) Foo<int>;
```

Note, how the extension is generating `Python` code, which allows you to do many sophisticated things.

Old answer:

According to the SWIG documentation the python layer is stripped off and thereby the `%extend` feature is ignored (this is incorrect, the proxy objects are not created)

See http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html

> 36.4.2 Built-in Types
>
> When -builtin is used, the pure python layer is stripped off. Each
>   wrapped class is turned into a new python built-in type which inherits
>   from SwigPyObject, and SwigPyObject instances are returned directly
>   from the wrapped methods. For more information about python built-in
>   extensions, please refer to the python documentation:

Comment: `%extend` applies at the C++ layer, not the Python layer so this isn't the answer here. The actual answer is in 36.4.2.2

Comment: @Flexo I have several examples using `%extend`, where the only effect is injection of code in the Python layer. Removal of the `built-in` flag works fine for me and of course referencing the object using `$self`.

Comment: Can you share one on pastebin or something? `%extend` is generic SWIG and not from the Python module, so I don't understand how that can be. `%pythoncode`, `%pythonprepend` and `%feature('shadow')` are all Python specific and won't do anything with -builtin, but `%extend` is as though your wrote it in your C or C++ declaration/definition

Comment: I write, `%extend Foo<int> { %pythoncode %{ def __getitem__(int i): ...`. In this way, the extension is only affecting the Python code. I have never used `%extend` without `%pythoncode`. I learn every day

Comment: Heh, I'd never used `%pythoncode` inside `%extend` and had always added more pure Python methods by 'monkey patching' with module level `%pythoncode`

Comment: I like your approach above - the more that gets translated to C, the better.